# How can divide image with size 1704 x 2272 into 128 x 128 patches?

Tags: matlab

I have image with size 1704 x 2272. I divide the image into 128 x 128 patches by matlab. the output y is cell but the column 18 is empty as attached file. pls can u help me to solve that.

My code is

```
       img = imread(filename);

        img = rgb2gray(img);

         img=size8cut(img);
         y=preprocess5(img);
```

.......................................................................................................

```
 function Y=size8cut(X) % cut the rim of the image, to make it more fit to be cut into 256*256 patches

    [m,n] = size(X);

   if mod(m,8)~=0

    X=X(1:m-mod(m,8),:);
   end

  if mod(n,8)~=0
  X=X(:,1:n-mod(n,8));
  end
  Y=X;
 end
```

................................................................................

```
    function blkim=preprocess5(im)  % cut the image into image patch with 128*128 size

[m n]=size(im);
i=ceil(m/128);
 j=ceil(n/128);
 blkim=cell(i,j);
 if i-1 ==0                 %% no zero dividsion
 overlap_m=0;
 else
overlap_m=(i*128-m)/(i-1);%compute the overlap between the patches
end

   if j-1 ==0
   overlap_n=0;
   else
    overlap_n=(j*128-n)/(j-1); %%%
    end
    if mod(overlap_m,8)~=0
    for count=1:32
       m=m-8;
       i=ceil(m/128);
      overlap_m=(i*128-m)/(i-1);
       if mod(overlap_m,8)==0
          break;
        end
          end
       end
     if mod(overlap_n,8)~=0
     for count=1:32
        n=n-8;
       j=ceil(n/128);
       overlap_n=(j*128-n)/(j-1);
        if mod(overlap_n,8)==0
           break;
          end
     end
 end
 im=im(1:m,1:n);
   for ii=1:i
    for jj=1:j
       blkim{ii,jj}=im((128-overlap_m)*(ii-1)+1:(128-overlap_m)*(ii-1)+128, (128-overlap_n)*(jj-1)+1:(128-overlap_n)*(jj-1)+128);
   end
 end
return;
end
```

Comment: We don’t want to read your code *guessing* what it’s supposed to do. Please explain it. How do you want to deal with the fact that 128 does not evenly divide your image dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

Image with size `1704 x 2272` cannot be equally divided into chunks of 128x128 since dimensions not a multiple of 128.

You might have to ignore or form a separate *patch* for it.

However if image is exact multiple of 128, you could simply use `mat2cell` with `repmat` as follows:

```
GrabPieces = @(X, chunks ) mat2cell( X, ...
       repmat(chunks,[1 size(X,1)/chunks]), ...
       repmat(chunks,[1 size(X,2)/chunks]) ...
       );
```

Then do,

```
P = GrabPieces ( img, 128 );
```

Comment: Nice variable name!